# Using Count with Case Statement (T-SQL)

Tags: sql, t-sql, count, max, case

The below query produces the following error message: "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery."

I'm trying to get a count of elements (loans) from a table based on certain criteria that I've put into a case statement. I'm using a case statement instead of simply inserting the criteria into the WHERE clause because I'm pulling multiple metrics with this single query and these criteria only apply to this specific metric and not the others. How can I fix it?

```
SELECT COUNT(
     CASE
          WHEN (SELECT CONVERT(DATE, MAX(Dates)) FROM (VALUES (S.SchedClosingDate), (S.SchedClosingDate)) AS SchedDates (Dates)) BETWEEN '05/01/18' AND '05/31/18' THEN FD.FileName
     END
     ) AS [Scheduled to Close]
FROM FileData AS FD
JOIN Status AS S ON FD.FileDataID = S.FileDataID
```

Note: I've removed the other metrics from the query for readability.

Answer (score 0):

Move the calculation to the `FROM` clause using `APPLY`:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN v.dte >= '2018-05-01' AND v.dte < '2018-06-01' AND
                     FD.FileName IS NOT NULL
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           END) AS [Scheduled to Close]
FROM FileData FD JOIN
     Status S
     ON FD.FileDataID = S.FileDataID CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT MAX(dte)
      FROM (VALUES (S.SchedClosingDate), (S.SchedClosingDate)) SchedDates(dte)
     ) as v(dte);
```